# Apache mod_rewrite .htaccess and conditions to avoid rewriting while url mysite.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to make custom URL for my users so they can have their personnal art gallery displayed just like on facebook when it displays user's profile . For instance   mysite.com/username will display username's gallery.

So basicaly what I've done now is something like that :

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/?$ index.php?fc=module&module=testmodule&controller=displaygallery&url=$1 [L]

I have the gallery correctly displayed on my website, but I can't display the index page anymore using absolute mysite.com. I know we can use conditions to avoid such a situation but which one ?

Answer (score 0):

So while writing the post I've just think about the line I've done and I found the solution ^^ !

Instead of using :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/?$ index.php?fc=module&module=testmodule&controller=displaygallery&url=$1 [L]
```

I'm now using :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?fc=module&module=testmodule&controller=displaygallery&url=$1 [L]
```

Instead of using * I used +, which is telling Apache that it needs at least one character or more to rewrite URL so everything works fine now :)